# Closure in $C([0,1])$ w.r.t. $\|\bullet\|_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $$\cal A=\left\{ f\in C([0,1]): |f(x)-f(y)|\leq5|x-y| \, \text{ for all  } x,y\in [0,1]\right\}$$ What's the closure of $\cal A$  in $C([0,1])$ with respect to the Supremum-Norm?

I think $\cal A$ is already closed and here is my potential proof: The map $C([0,1])\to \overline{ \Bbb R}$ sending $f$ to its Lipschitz constant if it exists, and to $\infty$ if there is no Lipschitz constant is continuous (is that true?) and therefore $\cal A$ is closed since it is the pre-image of the closed set $\{5\}\subset \Bbb R$.

Comment: It would be the pre-image of $[0,5]$, not of $\{5\}$. But the map $f \mapsto \operatorname{Lip}(f)$ is not continuous with respect to the supremum norm. $2^{-n}\cdot \sin (4^nx)$ has norm $2^{-n}$ and Lipschitz constant $2^n$. However, the map is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Good points. What's the best way to go about the exercise then?

Comment: Essentially, showing that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed is equivalent to showing that $f \mapsto \operatorname{Lip}(f)$ is lower semicontinuous. You can write $\mathcal{A}$ as an intersection of closed sets, or you can show that a pointwise limit of functions in $\mathcal{A}$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$. At the end of the day, both ways are doing the same, you just look at it from a different angle.

Comment: @DanielFischer So if $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\to 0$ for $(f_n)\subset \cal A$ then we also have pointwise convergence $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ and therefore $|f(x)-f(y)|=\lim_n |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq 5 |x-y|$? Is that alright?

Comment: That means $f\in \cal A$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I Appreciate the help!

Comment: @DanielFischer Can we say anything about the interior of $\cal A$? Is it empty?

Comment: Yes, we can, and yes, it's empty. You can again consider the $2^{-n}\sin (4^n x)$ to see it, or more abstractly note that $\mathcal{A}$ is contained in the proper linear subspace of Lipschitz-continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Every proper linear subspace in a topological vector space has empty interior.